# How to resume playback on an embedded mp4 video when a radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am creating a form based quiz which simply has groups of radio buttons and show the answers using jquery after they are selected. I have included embedded mp4 videos in each question- and they automatically play when the question loads- then they pause before the answer is revealed on the video timeline.... I want to resume playback once a radio button is active- when the question is answered. The issue I have run into is that simply hiding the divs won't work since you can hear the audio still. Any help would be appreciated.

Using CSS selectors with jQuery to try and simply hide the divs containing embedded videos, I have tried using SlickQuiz but am not sure how to set the parameters to include video in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to pause the video

```
$('.yourVideo').pause();
```

To play the video use the following

```
$('.yourVideo').play();
```